# Changing colour of text in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I need to change the colour of: 'Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value' Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value  to blue.

Can you help?

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Test As String



    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "yes" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next

             With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "TITLE" & " - " & Format(Now, "dd_mmmm_yyyy")

                .Body = Test & "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Text1" & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Text2'" & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & "TEXT" & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "TEXT3" & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "TEXT4" & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "TEXT5" & _
                        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Many thanks," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "DCX PMO Team"

                'Adding an attachment
                .Attachments.Add ("D:\Users\ABOHANNO\Desktop\Digital Transformation\tagging\DCX Sales Process.pptx")
                .Send  'Or use Display



            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Search on cells.interior.colorindex

Comment: Can you show me the code to use in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 cell.Resize(1,5).Font.Color = vbBlue
```

Comment: no sorry, it hasn't worked - do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Remove that `On Error Resume Next` from your code - you can't trouble-shoot with that in place.